# Nesting JSON from ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord

I have the following class hierarchy:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :project_personas
  has_many :personas, through: :project_personas
end

class ProjectPersona < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :persona
end

class Persona < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

and I'm trying to get a user as a JSON like that:

```
render json: @user.to_json(
  include: {
    projects: {
      include: :personas
    }
  })
```

what doesn't actually work. What is working is:

```
render json: @user.to_json(
    include: {
        projects: {
            include: {
                project_personas: {
                    include: :persona
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

but I don't want to have this `project_personas` level.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, the problem was trivial. I just needed to *include* projects. So

```
User.includes(projects: :personas).find_by(guid: '...')
```

and then I got projects with personas included.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand you question but would you mind providing more information?

You want the object and its relations in json?

@user = User.where(:persona => 'foo')
@user.to_json

Comment: Yes, but rather `User.where(:guid => '12-2-12')` and get the result `User { projects : { personas : { persona1, ...} } }`

Comment: what does that render in the console or browser when you query for that object?